# OpenGL ES 2.0 basic camera issues

Tags: android, camera, opengl-es2

I am having issues with the camera, I cant find how to invert the AXIS

Now

- A point is 0,0,0
- B point is 1,0,0
- C point is 0,0,1

What I want is

- A point    0,0,0
- B point    0,0,1
- C point    1,0,0

[image]

I cant find the way to do this, so if you can explain also why is this happening it will be great! (if you need more code ask for it)

Code:

```
final float eyeX = 2.0f;
    final float eyeY = 10f;
    final float eyeZ = 6.0f;

    final float lookX = 1.0f;
    final float lookY = 0.0f;
    final float lookZ = 6.0f;


    final float upX = 1.0f;
    final float upY = 0.0f;
    final float upZ = 0.0f;

    Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, lookX, lookY, lookZ, upX, upY, upZ);
```

ViewPort

```
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    final float ratio = (float) width / height;
    final float left = -ratio;
    final float right = ratio;
    final float bottom = -1.0f;
    final float top = 1.0f;
    final float near = 1.0f;
    final float far = 25.0f;
    Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `eyeY = -10`, `upX = 0`, and `upZ = 1`.  The other values can stay.

Your given and desired points suggest you want to rotate the camera position and its up vector about an axis parallel to `(1, 0, 1)` by angle `PI`.  Doing that would yield the values I listed above.

> Can you explain why this is happening?

It looks like you are getting exactly what you specified.  If you want a different result, change the values.